# Give the smallest value for 'a' to complete the graph

Tags: graph-theory, polar-coordinates

The curve $r=5\sinθ$ is given for $0\leθ\le a$
It appears that if $a = \pi$, the graph is complete. Now my question is why? Since I thought it should be $a = 2\pi$ since $2\pi = 360°$, which is a full circle.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plot the points at some spacing of $\theta$ you will see the graph is complete when $\theta=\pi$.  Because of the relationship $\sin (\theta+\pi)=-\sin (\theta)$ as $\theta$ rises from $\pi$ to $2\pi$ you have $r$ being negative, which reflects the angle through the center and retraces the graph you have already plotted.

Comment: But if the sin is negative, then theta is also negative right? Which is not allowed.

Comment: Usually $\theta$ is allowed to run over $(-\infty, \infty)$ and you plot enough of it to get what you want.  That doesn't matter in this case.  $\sin \frac {3\pi}2$ is negative even though  $\frac {3\pi}2$ is not

Comment: I see, so sin can be negative while theta remains strictly positive?

Comment: Sure.  Just plot $y=\sin x$ and you will see.  It is negative on $(\pi, 2\pi)$ and on all intervals $2k\pi$ above and below