# Smallest value of 'a' for which the graph of the curve $r = 4\sin2\theta$ is complete

Tags: graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

Recently, I asked for the smallest value of 'a' for which the graph of the curve $r = 5\sin\theta$ is complete. This turned out to be $\pi$ and not $2\pi$, because $\sin(\theta+\pi) = -\sin(\theta)$ ([Give the smallest value for 'a' to complete the graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3289998/give-the-smallest-value-for-a-to-complete-the-graph/3290010#3290010)). Now it turns out that the graph of the curve $r = 4\sin2\theta$ is complete for $a = 2\pi$. Now my question is why? I know that $\sin2\theta = 2\sin\theta \cos\theta$, but I still can't relate this property to that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apologies, I wrote down the wrong equation. It should be $r = 4\sin2\theta$

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you have $\sin 2(\theta+\pi)=\sin(2\theta+2\pi)=\sin2\theta$, so  geometrically, increasing the polar angle by $\pi$ induces a symmetry w.r.t. the origin.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is similar. There is a chance that $\theta+\pi$ and $\theta$ plot the same point. Let's see if that's the case.
Note that
$$r(\theta)=4\sin 2\theta=4\sin(2\theta+2\pi)=4\sin(2(\theta+\pi))=r(\theta+\pi)$$
Which means that the $r$ is the same, but the angles differ by $\pi$. Hence the points plotted are not the same, but opposite.